# Are Salary / Payment / Bonuses questions considered ontopic for PMSE?

Tags: discussion

Reading this [PM salary in the IT industry](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/6429/430) question, I wondered if any of these questions related to payment / salaries / bonuses are really PM questions.

Especially if we read the question raised by J related to [PMSE FAQ](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/444/430), I strongly believe they don't fit in.

Shouldn't they could be migrated to [worksplace.se?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Just so everyone is on the same page, let me start with a gentle reminder that the FAQ is *very* editable. Nothing is in stone. So if this is indeed a PM problem, we can definitely add it, especially if there is strong support. The FAQ is an excellent guideline for us, but it's also something we can continuously evolve.

With that said, I did find this discussion on [career questions, references, and former bosses](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/how-should-we-handle-career-questions-about-references-and-former-bosses). It seems the majority consensus is that those questions are off-topic.

As for questions about salary, I could see an argument either way. The advantages of having project managers answer questions about salary is that we have the first hand experience and knowledge about what to expect in this field, whereas general Workplace experts may not.

On the flip-side, workplace experts may have information about how to *find* and *locate* salary information for project managers, so this is a question that could very well be on-topic on either site.

One possible argument for marking those questions as off-topic is that they may distract from the bigger challenges in the PM field itself, and to me that could be an argument for marking them as off-topic if there is strong support. However, I don't recall seeing so many of these that they're a nuisance. No question is too basic or too simple, IMHO, so long as they don't detract from the overall value of the site.

Here is an important point to keep in mind, as we continue to discuss this issue, from [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/):

> **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

I *really* feel like our community does an excellent job of this.

---

### **Follow-up:**

**My Stance:**

I lean more towards migration and the faq edits you suggest, but it's not something I feel strongly enough about to make a decision on without more community support, or at least giving people an opportunity to weigh in and share the other viewpoints. I'm on the fence, so to speak. :)  Even when I'm not on the fence, I still prefer to get as much community support as I can.

**How to move forward:**

As it stands, there aren't any close votes on that question, and in order to discuss migrating a question, we would first need to determine that it's definitely not on topic on PMSE.

The first step in making changes on PMSE is to post a question in meta. That step is done, and we've started the conversation. The next step is getting others to participate:  If you feel strongly that these don't belong here, I'd suggest placing a close vote on the question itself. This will push it into the [review](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review) queue and into the [2K moderator tools](https://pm.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) menu so that it's on peoples' radar.

Additionally, it might be a good idea to jump into the [Workplace SE chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), drop a link to the question in there, and ask if they'd be interested in seeing if the post would have a home on Workplace SE.

In cases where I do feel strongly about something on our site and want to jump-start the discussions, I'll sometimes post a link to the meta discussion in the comments of the question, post a link in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management), or even @ping some users who I know might share my views or who I know would want to be involved.

*I also added the special* [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) *tag to your post, which will put it up on our [community bulletin board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130892/155826), located on the right hand side of the main page.*

If you do post comments, just be sure to clean them up after they serve their purpose. :)  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi J, I really appreciated your thoughtful answer, but is not clear your position on it. On the other hand, it seems that the community understands these questions as off-topic, so my suggestion would be to improve our FAQ one way (making it explicit that salary-related questions are off-topic) or another (making them on-topic). That was the initial  objective of my question :D

Comment: @TiagoCardoso, sorry for the delay. I updated my answer with some information that will hopefully be helpful. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hi @J, it seems we didn't get enough attention on it so far... I'd suggest as an action point to link this question next time we see a similar salary question around PMSE. What do you think?

Comment: @TiagoCardoso - Good idea!